# Website content filtering based on more than one filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, filtering

I have started learning JS and jQuery and have found a roadblock in one of the challenges that I can't figure out. I am rather new to this, so explanation would be extra helpful.

Fiddle showing what I have achieved: (it works, but not as intended): [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nauring/uaL7x1qr/89/)

```js
var filters1 = {
  "A": {
    "active": true
  },
  "B": {
    "active": true
  },
};

var filters2 = {
  "1": {
    "active": true
  },
  "2": {
    "active": true
  },
};

$(document).on('click', '.tag-filter', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id in filters1) {
    if (filters1[id].active) {
      filters1[id].active = false;
      $('.' + id).css("display", "none");
      $(this).addClass("active-tag-filter");
    } else {
      filters1[id].active = true;
      $('.' + id).css("display", "inline-block");
      $(this).removeClass("active-tag-filter");
    }
  } else if (id in filters2) {
    if (filters2[id].active) {
      filters2[id].active = false;
      $('.' + id).css("display", "none");
      $(this).addClass("active-tag-filter");
    } else {
      filters2[id].active = true;
      $('.' + id).css("display", "inline-block");
      $(this).removeClass("active-tag-filter");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
}

.tag-filter {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
}

.active-tag-filter {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='tag-filter' id='A'>A</div>
  <div class='tag-filter' id='B'>B</div>
  <div class='tag-filter' id='1'>1</div>
  <div class='tag-filter' id='2'>2</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div class='tag A 1'>A1</div>
  <div class='tag A 2'>A2</div>
  <div class='tag B 1'>B1</div>
  <div class='tag B 2'>B2</div>
</div>
```

##### What I want to achieve:

Good example worth more than a thousand works;
I want a filter like here: [Filtering Example](https://genshin.gg/); do some clicks and you will see what I mean.

In case an explanation is better:

1. When tag-filter from first group (letters) is activated, only tags with that letter are shown. Ex. When tag-filter A is clicked, only tags A1 and A2 are shown.
2. When another tag-filter from the same group is activated, the result is a sum.
   Ex. When tag-filter A is clicked and then B is clicked, tags A1, A2, B1, B2 are shown.
3. When user selects tag-filters from both groups. Clicking A > B > 1 in sequence.
   Ex. should show A1, A2 > show A1, A2, B1, B2 > Show A1 and B1.

It would be great if someone wants to write code for me, but more importantly, is this a good approach ? Is there a better way to do filtering like this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you editing an array?

Then I would suggest you to use the built in JS filter function. That way you can pass the already filtered array from f.e. group A and just filter it again - Would be the easiest way imo

Comment: I would do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/gtjuksx4/

Answer (score 0):

OP here. One of commenters suggested an array, which I made use of, in addition of hide() and show()  methods, that I knew of. Missing component was join() and filter() methods that were new for me. It was great learning experiance for me, thanks for help.

In the end here is working fiddle, with filtering working as I intended.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nauring/98pjvn36/38/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".filter-btn").click(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) 
    {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    } 
    else 
    {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
    
    var activeFilters1 = [];
    var activeFilters2 = [];
    $("#filter-container1 .filter-btn.active").each(function() {
      activeFilters1.push($(this).attr("data-filter"));
    });
    $("#filter-container2 .filter-btn.active").each(function() {
      activeFilters2.push($(this).attr("data-filter"));
    });
    
    if (activeFilters1.length === 0 && activeFilters2.length === 0) {
      // Show all items if no filters are active
      $(".item").show();
    } else if (activeFilters1.length > 0 && activeFilters2.length === 0) {
      // Show only items that match any of the active filters in the first group
      $(".item").hide().filter("." + activeFilters1.join(",.")).show();
    } else if (activeFilters1.length === 0 && activeFilters2.length > 0) {
      // Show only items that match any of the active filters in the second group
      $(".item").hide().filter("." + activeFilters2.join(",.")).show();      
    } else {
      // Show all items that match any of the active filters in the first group
      // Then refine the selection to only those that also match the active filters in the second group
      $(".item").hide().filter("." + activeFilters1.join(",.")).filter("." + activeFilters2.join(".")).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div id="filter-container1">
  <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="tagA">A</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="tagB">B</button>
</div>

<div id="filter-container2">
  <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="tag1">1</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="tag2">2</button>
</div>

<div id="item-container">
  <div class="item tagA tag1">Item tagged A and 1</div>
  <div class="item tagA tag2">Item tagged A and 2</div>
  <div class="item tagB tag1">Item tagged B and 1</div>
  <div class="item tagB tag2">Item tagged B and 2</div>
</div>
</html>
```